# Question not showing up in my Stack Exchange profile's 'Top Questions' after merging accounts

Tags: support, bug, questions, merge-accounts

On every Stack Exchange user's profile there's a list of their best posts with at least 5 votes, sorted into "Top Questions" and "Top Answers".

I just merged my account. [One of the questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355908/why-dont-multiple-decrement-operators-work-in-c-when-they-work-in-c) (originally from the other account) has 39 votes. It doesn't appear on my [Stack Exchange user profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/9221523/md-xf) Top Questions. Why?

Comment: These things are updated periodically.  I'd give it at least a day for the changes to be reflected in the database

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Yup, it's been 24 hours.